# C++ STL Map - find(pair<string,bool>) works in windows Visual Studio but not with g++ in Linux!

Tags: c++, stl, hash, dictionary, platform-specific

I seem to be having issues with using find() with the STL map on different platforms.  Here is my code to be complete:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

void constructDictionary(map<string,bool> &dict);
bool isInDictionary(string word, map<string,bool> &dict);

int main(void)
{

    map<string, bool> dictionary;
    constructDictionary(dictionary);
    map<string, bool>::iterator it = dictionary.begin();

    while(it != dictionary.end()){
        cout << it->first <<endl;
        it++;
    }

    string word;
    while(true){
        cout << "Enter a word to look up: " << endl;
        cin >> word;
        if(isInDictionary(word, dictionary))
            cout << word << " exists in the dictionary." << endl;
        else
            cout << word << " cannot be found in the dictionary." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void constructDictionary(map<string,bool> &dict)
{
    ifstream wordListFile;
    wordListFile.open("dictionaryList.txt");
    string line;

    while(!wordListFile.eof()){
        getline(wordListFile, line);
        dict.insert(pair<string,bool>(line, true));
    }

    wordListFile.close();
}

bool isInDictionary(string word, map<string,bool> &dict)
{
    if(dict.find(word) != dict.end())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

`isInDictionary()` works fine if compiled using visual studio in windows, however, on ubuntu and g++, this only works for the last entry made into the map.  Any other word that I query returns false.  I don't understand the discrepancy in this behavior.  In both cases, the while statement at the beginning of main correctly prints out everything in the map to prove that everything's there.

Any ideas?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the error in getline and line-endings in your input file? You might find on Linux it is adding an extra `\r` to each word.

Assuming none of your words contain spaces, you can get around this by simply using:

```
std::string word;
while( wordListFile >> word )
{
   if( !word.empty() )
   {
       // do the insert
   }
}
```

You can also use getline but "trim" the strings at either end. There is unfortunately no standard trim function. There are a few implementations around.

You should probably use std::set as your collection type instead of this extra "bool" which is always true whenever there is an entry.

Comment: I was under the impression that STL map was a hash map and thus O(1) look-up complexity but upon further investigation I can see that that is *not* the case.  Agreed, set would be better.

Comment: @Jon: Your impression is wrong. STL maps require an ordering on the keys, and usually use a tree-based implementation. Hence they have O(log n) lookup complexity. [Boost.Unordered](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/unordered.html) provides a hash-based map though.

Comment: ended up using an unordered set.

Answer (score 3):

- while (!eof) is wrong. Use `while (getline(...))`
- You need to handle the windows linefeed `\r\n`. Likely your dictionary is generated on windows, and the last line doesn't have a linefeed, so all words except the last has a hidden `\r` at the end.

Comment: Both points are valid... will definitely change the while termination condition (doh!) and will look into stripping anything off the end of those strings.  Getting too late to do it now.  Will report back tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, the while(!eof) is wrong too, it will result in the last key getting "inserted" twice, not that it actually will as map (and set) ensure uniqueness.